# Two C Makefile projects, one used by the other

Tags: c, makefile

I have two C projects which use Makefiles. One provides a library which I want to use in the other project. To be more specific, the structure is as follows

```
.
├── hiredis
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── hiredis.h
│   └── ...
├── qemu
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── source_code.c
│   └── ...
```

Inside the qemu project -  in some file `source_code.c` - I want to include the `hiredis.h` header file. I don't think simply adding the hiredis directory into the qemu tree would be the right way.

What is the best way to use the library inside the qemu project (without an IDE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hiredis` and `qemu` are always in the same tree at fixed/know position, I would use a `-I../hiredis` CPP flag.

For flexibility you can parameterise the position of `hiredis`.  But I would only do this when really needed; it's so relaxing to keep things simple.

BTW, using Makefiles without IDE are great: full control and insight.  So enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried adding the cflag using `./configure ... -I<path-to-hiredis>`, which seems to work. But when I call `make`, I get an `undefined reference` error from `ld`. Do i need to add some ldflags, too?

Comment: Of course the linker needs to know the location of the `hiredis` binary file(s).  It's common to combine all object (`.o`) in a single archive `libhiredis.a` (prefix `lib` is needed).  Then you need to add `-L<directory-of-hiredis-archive>` and `-lhiredis` `LDFLAGS`.  Please 'plus' my answer and these comments as my rewards :-)